# Change JSON output for autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I need to chagen my JSON output which is:

> [
>   {
>   masterCardNo: 90363.01
>   },
>   {
>   masterCardNo: 90363.02
>   },
>   {
>   masterCardNo: 90363004
>   },
>   {
>   masterCardNo: 90363004
>   },
>   {
>   masterCardNo: 90363004
>   },
>   {
>   masterCardNo: 90363004
>   },
>   {
>   masterCardNo: 90363004
>   },
>   {
>   masterCardNo: 90363004
>   },
>   {
>   masterCardNo: 90363004
>   },
>   {
>   masterCardNo: 2906.01
>   }
>   ]

To Something like this:

> [ "90363004", "90363001", "90363003"]

I have my output in a variable named "value"...

Thanks for any help..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) to convert the array of object to array of desired structure

```
var value = [{
    masterCardNo: 90363.01
}, {
    masterCardNo: 90363.02
}, {
    masterCardNo: 90363004
}, {
    masterCardNo: 90363004
}, {
    masterCardNo: 90363004
}, {
    masterCardNo: 90363004
}, {
    masterCardNo: 90363004
}, {
    masterCardNo: 90363004
}, {
    masterCardNo: 90363004
}, {
    masterCardNo: 2906.01
}]

value = $.map(value, function(obj){
    return obj.masterCardNo
});

console.log(value)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Ugq9z/)

Comment: @Fahad for autocomplete it will work fine... if you still want http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Ugq9z/2/

Comment: its working there... (only with hard coded string)
but when I use my variable, it does not...
I made sure that variable returns same format as of working string...

Answer (score 1):

```
var json = '[numbers { masterCardNo: 90363.01 }, { masterCardNo: 90363.02 }, { masterCardNo: 90363004 }, { masterCardNo: 90363004 }, { masterCardNo: 90363004 }, { masterCardNo: 90363004 }, { masterCardNo: 90363004 }, { masterCardNo: 90363004 }, { masterCardNo: 90363004 }, { masterCardNo: 2906.01 } ]';

var json_parsed = $.parseJSON(json);
var no = "[";
for (var i = 0; i < json_parsed.numbers.length; i++){

 no += json_parsed.numbers[i].masterCardNo+",";
}
no+="]";
```

try this

u can also edit as u want for some changes

Answer (score 0):

convert it into string & replace `'{'` into `""`

use replace keyword for that

http://www.dotnetperls.com/replace

or

you can do it using same replace keyword in javascript

for better understand check this link:  jsfiddle.net/Mrw8k/2

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mrw8k/2)

```
var data1 = "[{ masterCardNo: 90363.01 }, { masterCardNo: 90363.02 }, { masterCardNo: 90363004 }, { masterCardNo: 90363004 }, { masterCardNo: 90363004 }, { masterCardNo: 90363004 }, { masterCardNo: 90363004 }, { masterCardNo: 90363004 }, { masterCardNo: 90363004 }, { masterCardNo: 2906.01 }]";
    for (i = 0; i < data1.split(',').length; i++) {
        data1 = data1.replace(" masterCardNo:", "");
        data1 = data1.replace("{", '"');
        data1 = data1.replace("}", '"');
    }

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = data1;
```

Comment: you can do it in to javascript also

Comment: @MaTya after removing `{` this what you have got...just check what is the question

Comment: sir @Blender you can do it using same replace keyword in javascript also check this link http://jsfiddle.net/Mrw8k/2/

Comment: @nilesh check the O/P again

Comment: @MaTya: JSON is a format that can be parsed *directly* into a JavaScript object. Manipulating strings will break JSON like `{foo: "{}"}`.

Comment: @blender i know that we can parse it but i gave a suggestion u can do it from this way also.. & what u do after parse u will not get this type of o/p [ "90363004", "90363001", "90363003"] ...so then why r u trying to parse it...

Comment: @MaTya: Because search and replace will break your JSON. You parse data formats into data structures because objects are easy to work with: `obj.map(function(elem) { return elem.masterCardNo; })`.

Comment: @Blender [ "90363004", "90363001", "90363003"] this is not a json format if u use map u will get only 90363004, 90363001, 90363003 and again u have to format it in this [ "90363004", "90363001", "90363003"] so jst replace it, it is simple solution for those who dont knw map function.

Answer (score 0):

Try using @MatYa Answer

check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Mh22s/

```
  data1 = data1.replace("{ masterCardNo:",'');
    data1 = data1.replace("}",'');
```